# C++ primer exercise 1.5.1 p 1.20

Tags: c++

Exercise 1.20: http://www.informit.com/title/032174113 contains a copy of `Sales_item.h` in the Chapter 1 code directory. Copy that file to your working directory. Use it to write a program that reads a set of book sales transactions, writing each transaction to the standard output.

The link it provides does not work, so I downloaded `Sales_item.h` from another website.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main()
{
    Sales_item sales_item;
    while (std::cin >> sales_item)
        std::cout << sales_item << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error say:

> Sales_item.h : **No such file or directory found**

Note: I am using Windows 7 and Code::Blocks.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a build system to find a file? It might depend on the build system.

Comment: This means that you either have not copied the file, or forgot to add a reference to it to the project in your IDE.

Comment: In which directory is your header downloaded and which compiler/ ide do You use?

Comment: I am using windows Os and how to add reference in a project ?
The book says something like add 
$ addItems <infile>outfile

Comment: I removed the tag **primer** because it's not helpful, read the tag info.

Comment: It would be better if you answer my question instead of editing

Comment: Your compiler didn't find `Sales_item.h`, specify what compiler and  options you are using.

Comment: I am using codeblocks

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `Sales_item.h` source code from the internet, then paste it in your editor, then save the file as `Sales_item.h` format thus a header file will be created in the same folder where all your program is saved. Now copy the newly created header file and paste it in your working directory.

The directory is located in `windowC:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`,`folder where most of the header files are saved. Save your`sales_item` header file there.

Then compile and run your code smoothly.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you suggesting to make three distinct copies of the file, one of them by hand?

Comment: No I want you to make one header file. from the code as already available at net. and paste at the location mention above

Comment: Then what's with _"copy the newly created header file and paste it in your working directory"_? Then _"Save your `sales_item` header file there"_?

Comment: you have to convert the source code of Sales_item into header file format by just saving it as .h format and that header file you have to store in your include directory. "copy the newly created header file and paste it in your working directory" that is the main task.

Comment: Don't know why you keep saying "you"; it's not me

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
#include "./Sales_item.h"
```

You might be getting the error because the linking to Sales_item.h was set incorrectly.